Equation not rendered in helper files of function of html pages
I am building a package and an associated website (via Github Pages). Let's say I have a function funX. In R, when I do ?funXI have some equations (using \eqn{} or \deqn{}) in the description files, and they are rendered well in LaTeX within R interface.
However, when I go to the website generated by pkgdown, it's the only equations of the entire site that do not show properly. For example \eqn{X=Y}would show:  \(X=Y\) on the website.
This is puzzling because in all the other vignettes the equations are rendered with mathjax without any problem. So maybe it's a specificity of the .Rd files vs the .Rmd?
In my _pkgdown.yml file, I have:
template:
  mathjax: true

What could be the issue?

Maybe you need to provide the ASCII too. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Mathematics

I tried to also specify the ascii, it does not do anything unfortunately!

You aren't giving people here much code to work with.

Is that all you have in your _pkgdown.yml file?  When I use only that the mathjax works fine.  If I also add bootstrap: 5 to the template: entry, I see the problem you described.

See this page:  https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/articles/customise.html .
In summary, if you are using
template:
  bootstrap: 5

then you also need
  math-rendering: mathjax

in the same template: section.

Thanks, this works! Indeed I had bootstrap: 5 (which is created by default I think).
Now, the math-rendering is not as beautiful as before on the other pages though, but I guess I can customize this! Thanks a lot :)

The thing is, using math-rendering: mathjax does not yield the same math (on the entire website) as the default with bootstrap: 5.
I like how bootstrap: 5 works (because I'm using custom templates as well).
Do you have any other idea how I could force mathjax rendering on the reference pages? I still don't understand why it does not work there.

You should edit your question as requested, and at the same time include this modification to your question.  We really have very little idea what you have done.
